# PyTesseract Missing = in configvar assignment

Tags: python-tesseract

[This is the code and the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jS0.png)I am trying to implement an ALPR sytstem using OpenCV and PyTesseract. When I try to run the code, I receive this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 25, in <module>
    predictedResult = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang ='eng', config ='--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
  File "/home/orhun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 413, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/home/orhun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 416, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/home/orhun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 284, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/orhun/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "read_params_file: Can't open = read_params_file: Can't open ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 Missing = in configvar assignment")
```

What can I do to fix it? Please help!

Comment: If possible, could you please add your code along with the example image?

Comment: @Ahx I added. It is my first time using stackoverflow so, I added in the beginning.

Comment: Did you try removing the spaces between the `tessedit_char_whitelist = ABCD...`?

Answer (score 3):

If you followed tutorial from [www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/license-plate-recognition-with-opencv-and-tesseract-ocr/), you can change **config** variable from:

```
config ='--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

to:

```
config ='--oem 3 --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

I got this solution from [www.pyimagesearch.com](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/09/21/opencv-automatic-license-number-plate-recognition-anpr-with-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces left and right side of =
-->.....whitelist=ABCD....